# How to identify objects in array that have similar time events

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and I am looking to identify objects if they are within a given time range of each other and from the same location. That is, I have multiple events that happen but if they occurred within x amount of time from each other in the same location then I need to identify them and dive deeper into it to check if it a form of duplication. If it is not a duplication then I continue along the array picking up the new object and checking the subsequent objects within the range.

```
[
  {
    time: '05:30:32',
    epochtime: 1611372632882,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372343379000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:31:59',
    epochtime: 1611372719261,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372634481000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:32:33',
    epochtime: 1611372753736,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372715502000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:32:42',
    epochtime: 1611372762248,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372634481000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:33:24',
    epochtime: 1611372804246,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372798767000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  }
]
```

Sample Output:

```
[
  {
    time: '05:30:32',
    epochtime: 1611372632882,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372343379000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:32:33',
    epochtime: 1611372753736,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372715502000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    time: '05:32:42',
    epochtime: 1611372762248,
    locationvalue: 1,
    objectId: 1611372634481000,
    locationame: 'Location 2'
  }
]
```

Object with ObjectId: 1611372634481000 and 1611372798767000 were removed from the array as after investigation they were indeed duplication events.

So in the above, I see that the first object (1611372343379000) occurred at Location 2 at epoch time of 1611372632882. The next object also occurred at the same location at epoch time of 1611372719261 (which is 1 and a half minutes later). So if it is within 3 minutes, I need to identify this second event and remove it or ignore it (once I call an external function on this object to investigate if real or a duplicate). The subsequent (next) object might also be a duplication so because it falls into the 3 minutes difference, I need to identify it and then investigate it as well (until I am out of the 3 minute time difference). Then I continue to the next object (if it wasn't deleted from the array by the investigation) and repeat until I am out of the 3 minutes range.

The net result is that I have a degree of confidence that objects that are leftover are indeed unique and not duplication (my in-depth function identifies that), for now, I just need to understand how to identify the object that has the same location and falls within an epoch time of the currently selected object.

Appreciated.

Comment: can you show a sample output of the input that you shared?

Comment: Added a sample output showing that some of the objects were removed as the investigation function showed they were duplication.

Comment: You could try sorting this array by `locationname` and then by `epochtime` (if `locationname`s are the same) and loop through this sorted array and check if next element is contained in your time margin :)

Comment: @Dug so even if there are duplicate Ids in same location but are not withing x amount of time from each other, we will keep that in the output array or you just want to remove duplicate element from same location in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting your array by `epochtime` and `locationname` you can use a `filter()` call along with a pointer tracking the element to compare against.

You'll need to convert your time threshold to milliseconds to compare against the difference of your epochtimes. Each time an element falls outside of the threshold or the locationnames don't match, update the pointer and continue.

```js
const input = [
  { time: '05:30:32', epochtime: 1611372632882, locationame: 'Location 2' },
  { time: '05:32:42', epochtime: 1611372762248, locationame: 'Location 1' },
  { time: '05:32:33', epochtime: 1611372753736, locationame: 'Location 2' },
  { time: '05:31:59', epochtime: 1611372719261, locationame: 'Location 1' },
  { time: '05:33:24', epochtime: 1611372804246, locationame: 'Location 2' }
];

const filterEventsByProximity = (arr, thresholdMinutes) => {
  let
    thresholdMs = thresholdMinutes * 6e4, // threshold in ms
    pointer = 0;
  arr.sort((a, b) => a.epochtime - b.epochtime); // sort ascending by epochtime
  arr.sort((a, b) => a.locationame.localeCompare(b.locationame)); // sort by locationname
  return arr.filter(({ epochtime, locationame }, i, a) => {
    if (i) { // skip the first element
      if (Math.abs(epochtime - a[pointer].epochtime) < thresholdMs && locationame === a[pointer].locationame) {
        return false;
      } else {
        pointer = i;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log('\n1mins: ')
console.log(filterEventsByProximity(input, 1));

console.log('\n3mins: ')
console.log(filterEventsByProximity(input, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for. Question though; once it finds the next item that is under X minutes away and I do a check (in the return false area), does it then continue to the next element to check if it too was under X minutes away? Or does it progress to the next element in the array and start the process again (checking it then the next one)?

Comment: I'm not sure what your secondary check is, but after a `return` (either true or false) it will iterate the next item in the array, comparing it against the element at the `pointer` index. If your secondary check is going to change whether the element should be kept, you'll need to update the pointer appropriately.